# Kubuntu dosen't open anything at startup?

Tags: kde, kubuntu, plasma

I had installed kubuntu 15.04 a few weeks back.

Till now it had worked fine.

But somehow it has started to behave oddly.

I do see it boot and am greeted with the plasma login screen but after I login I just see my mouse pointer and a black scree. When I press `alt + space`  I see the Krunner but when I type in the box It doesn't do any thing.

Its same after4 `startx` it just restarts plasma and i am again ending up with the cursor.

the result of ls -l etc is as below

[image]

I have tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but I don't know what to do after I get the console with the login option.

Answer (score 0):

At the console, login using your username. After that you will be prompted for your password. If this is your first time in the console, be aware that typing the password will not put any characters on the screen. Hit return when you have finished entering your password.

Now you should be at the login shell. I don't know that you've provided us with enough detail, but you could start by typing `startx`, hitting return, and updating your question with the output of that command.

Also, if the desktop environment doesn't start after running `startx`, please post the output of `ls -l $HOME/.Xauthority`

Comment: pls check updated question

Comment: Well, that looks as it should. When you are at the plasma login screen, there should be a menu that says something like "Session" or "Session Type." Make sure that you've selected something that says "kde" or "kubuntu," and try logging in.